# SRSS Reporting Issues

Tags: c#, sql, reporting

```
SELECT tp.ProjectName, tp.ProjectDescription, dev.FullName as 'Developer'
        , o.FullName as 'Owner', tp.StartDate, tp.EndDate, tp.ProjectStatus, 
        tp.CompletionPct, Count(tb.ProjectID) as 'NumberofBugs'

FROM tblBTProject tp
LEFT JOIN tblBTBugs tb ON tp.ProjectID = tb.ProjectID

--Get user fullnames by ID
LEFT JOIN CollectionsOperationsControl.dbo.tblCOCUser as dev 
    ON tp.Developer = dev.CorpID
LEFT JOIN CollectionsOperationsControl.dbo.tblCOCUser as o 
    ON tp.Owner = o.CorpID


WHERE CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), tp.CreationDate, 101) AS DATETIME) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
AND (tp.Developer  IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.fnSplitList(LTRIM(RTRIM(@Developer)), ',')))
AND (tp.Owner IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.fnSplitList(LTRIM(RTRIM(@Owner)), ',')))


GROUP BY tp.ProjectID, tp.ProjectName, tp.ProjectDescription, dev.FullName, o.FullName, tp.StartDate, tp.EndDate, 
            tp.ProjectStatus, tp.CompletionPct

ORDER BY tp.ProjectID
```

In the above code I want to return a count of all instances of tp.ProjectID in tblBTBugs (on the join by tp.ProjectID from tblBTProject) I have done this as a store procedure but in my reporting services when I do a multiple select on the 'Developer' and 'Owner' it shows only one instance of each 'Developer' or 'Owner' and not all the records that match. Is it an issue with the join where it returns only one instance of each?
Thanks
P.S. I am using SQL Server 2005 for the stored procedure. The parameters for it are @StartDate, @EndDate, @Developer & @Owner
fnSplitList helps with the multiple value select of 'Developer' and 'Owner' in SRSS

On the report side I am using =JOIN(Parameters!Developer.Value, “,”) for the splitting of records

Comment: Can you add the definition of the parameter on the report side, i.e. are you using =Join(...) in the parameter to return a comma delimited string?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using the usual SSRS handling of Multi-value parameters: simply use `tp.Developer in ( @Developer )`

Comment: 'tp.Developer  IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.fnSplitList(LTRIM(RTRIM(@Developer)), ',')'

Comment: I figured it out. I was not using 'SELECT DISTINCT' on the 'Owners